# How to test if a struct contains specific members by SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, sfinae

In order to define overloaded functions to parse an input string to specific data type, I do like below:

```
#include <type_traits>

//  /std:c++17 enabled

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_point_v = std::is_class_v<T> && !std::is_enum_v<T>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
&& (sizeof(T) == sizeof(T::y) + sizeof(T::y));

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_rect_v = std::is_class_v<T> && !std::is_enum_v<T>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::left)>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::top)>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::right)>
&& std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::bottom)>
&& (sizeof(T) == sizeof(T::left) + sizeof(T::top) + sizeof(T::right) + sizeof(T::bottom));


template<typename T>
struct Point {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>
        x {}, y {};

    Point() noexcept {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Rect {
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T>
        left {}, top {}, right {}, bottom {};

    Rect() noexcept {}
};

class DBParser
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T> || std::is_same_v<T, std::string> || std::is_same_v<T, std::string_view>, T>
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue = {}) { 
        // ...
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if_t<is_point_v<T>, T> 
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue = {}) {
        // ...
        return defaultValue;
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if_t<is_rect_v<T>, T> 
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue = {}) {
        // ...
        return defaultValue;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    DBParser db;
    auto point1 = db.get<Point<int>>("point1", {});
    auto point2 = db.get<Point<float>>("point2", {});
    auto rect1 = db.get<Rect<int>>("rect1", {});
    auto rect2 = db.get<Rect<float>>("rect2", {});
    auto ret3 = db.get<int>("key3", {});
}
```

Compiling the code above gives a tone of errors. Obviously the SFINAE I did for the functions "get" are incorrect and somewhat clumsy but I could not figure it out.

Could you give me some fixes for the code? In the case C++17 could not make the code less verbose, I accept C++20.

**UPDATE:**

In order to make the question is more appropriate to the issue, I want to change the title and add more information.
One thing strange is if I put the testing of struct directly to the functions like this:

```
template <class T>
    std::enable_if_t < std::is_class_v<T> && !std::is_enum_v<T>
            && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::x)>
            && std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(T::y)>
            && (sizeof(T) == sizeof(decltype(T::x)) + sizeof(decltype(T::y))), T>
        get(const char* key, T defaultValue) { // Point
        return defaultValue;
}
```

It get compiled without errors. So I think the assumption from Nicol Bolas may be not correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not how you do SFINAE on types (ie: putting `enable_if` on their members). I'm also pretty sure that all your `decltype(T::whatever)` things don't work either, since those would be member pointers, not the members themselves.

Comment: @NicolBolas Hi Nicol, I have updated my question with mention on your comment.